# Cannot allocate vector of size

Tags: r

I'm trying to do an operation with a matrix, I try to do it but it gives me this error, what can I do?

```
> freq2 <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm2))
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1254.4 Gb
```

Comment: Does your system have 1254.5 GB of memory?

Comment: Not knowing anything about `dtm2`, we can assume that it's not a small object. Lots of rows and columns? If you can share representative data (the output from `dput(dtm2[1:20,1:10])`, we might be able to find workarounds.

Comment: `colSums` should work on tabular data of any class, you probably don't need `as.matrix`.